# How to define global final variable that not changes for all tests under class?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I write unit test in Swift.

I call my app method and through `delegate` get back JSON object that represents request.

Now I want to validate all fields of JSON. Each validation should be in separate test.

This is what I wrote:

```
class LaunchTests: XCTestCase, TestServerHandlerDelegate {

    var theExpectation:XCTestExpectation?

    var launchRequest:String? = nil   

    public func onSend(_ data: Data!) {        
        launchRequest = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)         
        theExpectation?.fulfill()
    }

override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        // we wait in setUp till get 'launchRequest'
        if launchRequest == nil {

            theExpectation = expectation(description: "initialized") 

             MyApp.shared().setDelegate(self)            
             MyApp.shared().launch()

            // Loop until the expectation is fulfilled in onDone method
            waitForExpectations(timeout: 500, handler: { error in XCTAssertNil(error, "Oh, we got timeout")})
        }
    }

override func tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
}

func test___01_platform(){
    if let _ = fetchJsonValue(key: "somekey", value: launchRequest){
        //...
    }
}

func test___02_platform(){
    if let _ = fetchJsonValue(key: "platform", value: launchRequest){
        //...
    }
}
```

The problem is: for each run `launchRequest` is `nil`. I know that its right behavior but I want to call `MyApp.shared().launch()` once only and run multiple tests for `launchRequest` data.

How can I achieve it?

(I know its not good practice for unit testing but anyways)

Thanks,

Comment: did you try to set `static launchRequest` ?

Comment: Do you send a request to a (web) server in the `setUp` method? And what exactly are you trying to test in `test___01_platform`?

Comment: @MichałCiuba Generally I call my App `launch` method that sends HTTP request. I don't mock server handler (tried swizzing and OCMock - doesn't work) so I just register with callback and get back request as JSON string

Comment: OK, you can still write a mock server class yourself, so your tests don't depend on the "real" HTTP request. I would suggest trying a different approach in your tests, but I still don't know what exact behavior are you trying to test in `test___02_platform` method.

Comment: @MichałCiuba in all tests I get JSON request, parse it with SwiftyJSON and validate fields.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood your responses, but instead of sending network response and parsing the response, could you just pass a pre-defined JSON data in your test? And then check if your parsing logic handles it appropriately.

Comment: @MichałCiuba not at all, i run my app with predefined configuration and check what JSON the app created. This is a goal

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you really want that, you can just put `launchRequest` outside of your `LaunchTests` class:

```
var launchRequest:String? = nil

class LaunchTests: XCTestCase, TestServerHandlerDelegate {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to define `launchRequest` as `static` (as Maxim Shoustin mentioned):

```
static var launchRequest:String? = nil
```

In this case everything works as expected